# Prove that $A$ is locally closed if and only if $A$ is the intersection of open and closed set.

Tags: general-topology

> A subspace $A$ of a topological space $X$ is locally closed if for every $a \in A$ there exists a neighborhood $O$ of $a$ such that $A \cap O \subset O$ is closed. Prove that $A$ is locally closed if and only if $A$ is the intersection of open and closed set.

Assume first that $A$ is locally closed. Then for every $a \in A$ there exists $O_a$ such that $A \cap O_a$ is closed in $O_a$. Now the neighborhoods $O_a$ cover $A$ so we have that $\bigcup_{a \in A} O_a \supseteq A$. Can I use this to show that $A$ is the intersection of some open and closed set?

Comment: What does it mean that a set is closed in $O_a$?

Comment: If $A \cap O_a$ is closed in $O_a$, then $A \cap O_a = O_a \cap F$ for some $F$ closed in $O_a$? @HennoBrandsma

Comment: No, some $F$ closed in $X$ even. Otherwise you add no info.

Comment: How does this help? Do I need to consider the closure of $A$ here? The proposed question that has answers relies on something called nets that I have not covered and I am looking for something that doesn't rely on nets/sequences.

Comment: In your text, is a neighbourhood always open?

Comment: Maybe this. I have a result that if $E \subset A$, then $\operatorname{cl}_A(E) = A \cap \overline{E}$, where $\overline{E}$ is the closure w.r.t to $X$. So in my case I have that $$A \subset \bigcup_{a \in A} O_a \subset X.$$ Now applying this I get that $$\operatorname{cl}_{\bigcup_{a \in A} O_a} (A) = \bigcup_{a \in A} O_a \cap \overline{A}.$$ But $A$ is closed in $O_a$ for every $a$ so $\operatorname{cl}_{\bigcup_{a \in A} O_a} (A) = A$ implying that $$A =  \bigcup_{a \in A} O_a \cap \overline{A}.$$ Would this work? Equality $\operatorname{cl}_{\bigcup_{a \in A} O_a} (A) = A$ concerns me.

Comment: doesn’t work in that form as unions do not commute with closures. You haven’t answered the neighbourhood question?

Comment: Trying figure it out. By neighborhood I assume you meant some $O_a$?

Comment: You say there must be a neighbourhood (open?) $O$ such that $A\xap O$ is closed in it. What does neighbourhood mean there?

Comment: For each $a \in A$ pick an open set $O_a$ containing $a$ so that $F_a \cap O_a = O_a \cap A$ for a closed set $F_a$ of $X$. Define $O=\bigcup_{a \in A} O_a$. I claim that $O \cap \overline{A} = A$.